# Unable to declare variable in onload attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I was creating a web page, in which an image moves horizontally until the 'stop me' button is pressed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var count = 0;
            function move(){
                image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
                count++;
                image.style.left = count;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "var temp = setInterval(move,1)">
        <img src = "facebook_icon.png" style = "position:absolute; left = 0; top:0;">
        <br>
        <button onclick = "clearInterval(temp);">Click here to stop the loop.</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I remove the var keyword from the `onload` attribute, the code runs fine.
New code:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var count = 0;
            function move(){
                image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
                count++;
                image.style.left = count;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "temp = setInterval(move,1)">
        <img src = "facebook_icon.png" style = "position:absolute; left = 0; top:0;">
        <br>
        <button onclick = "clearInterval(temp);">Click here to stop the loop.</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why is it so?

Comment: `var` is in the second code too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope issue: variables declared in the attribute are not global, example:

```
<body onload = "var temp = 'hello'; alert(temp);">
     <button onclick = "alert(temp);">Click</button>
</body>
```

In the above example, on page load, an alert will show the message `hello`. But, when you click the button you get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: temp is not defined`. This means that the variable `temp` is not accessible (not global).

However, assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable, that's why your second example works fine:

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

CSS

```
<style>
 #container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
            background: yellow;
        }
        #animate {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
            <img src="images/up.png" id="animate"  />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <button onclick="myStopFunction()">Click here to stop the loop.</button>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myMove() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
            var pos = 0;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
            function frame() {
                if (pos == 350) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                    pos++;
                    elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
                    elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
                }
            }
        }
        function myStopFunction() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
            clearInterval(myMove());
        }
    </script>
```